# MySQL allow access from specific domain?

Tags: mysql, linux

I'm trying to allow access to the MySQL instance I have running on a local server here. I know I can bind remote access to certain IP's and certain IP ranges in the my.cnf file. I was curious if it was possible to allow access from entire domains rather than having to list out all the possible IP's that might be connecting.

I know you can grant access to entire domains via the GRANT command but i guess my disconnect is how the my.cnf file works with this.

Example if I

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mydatabase.* to jsmith@'somedomain' IDENTIFIED BY 'jimspassword';
```

but then don't have any IP's bound in the my.cnf file will it still work?

thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As documented under [`GRANT` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/grant.html):

> #### Account Names and Passwords
>
> ```
> [ deletia ]
> ```
>
> You can specify wildcards in the host name. For example, `user_name@'%.example.com'` applies to *`user_name`* for any host in the `example.com` domain, and `user_name@'192.168.1.%'` applies to *`user_name`* for any host in the `192.168.1` class C subnet.

Comment: SO the my.cnf file doesn't need to be edited to allow this? Thats my main confusion I think. I've created a test user and given him access via GRANT but when i try to connect to the MYSQL instance it doesn't work. It's almost like the server is not allowing connections at all. I can however connect from the server itself.. ie "localhost"

Comment: @TheSnooker: This will cause MySQL to *authenticate* a user connecting from a host within the relevant domain; but it does not necessarily ensure that inbound connections will reach MySQL at all.  There may be a firewall or other network filters in place.